# Google Places Autocomplete, how to deal with Unit number in the address

Tags: javascript, regex, google-places-api, google-places

I'm using [Google Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) to allow user to provide address and it works mostly fine for basic addresses e.g.

```
Some st Ashfield NSW 2019
```

But it doesn't work when someone provides additional info like unit number e.g.:

```
Unit 2/42, Some st Ashfield NSW 2019
```

What would be the best way to deal with this kind of address given that Unit might be Apartment and in all different formats. Some crazy regex or is there any setting in Google Autocomplete I missed? Or just provide additional field for Unit/Appartment/everything else is the only option?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Place API Unit Number not fetching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51152662/google-place-api-unit-number-not-fetching)

Comment: Support for subpremise elements (apt. / suite) is limited. Place Autocomplete is not intended to support these universally. Status: Won't Fix (Intended Behavior)
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35830389#comment3

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when saving my contacts' addresses and wanting Google Maps to show them on my everyday maps. What I ended up using was... parenthesis!

Depends on what country you are on and what you type, but for instance

```
King Street 5, Ashfield NSW 2019
```

Works, obviously, but it doesn't have the unit number.

```
King Street 5 (Unit 2/42), Ashfield NSW 2019
```

Works with the unit number (although there is not difference as far as the marker is concerned).

Please note: I have no idea how addresses in Australia work, but Google seems to "rename" the address you type if you type it on Google maps (I have used it in countries I have lived and the renaming works perfectly).

Hope it helps!